# Какой пакет Mono выбрать?

Tags: c#, mono, ubuntu

Решил поставить `Mono` на `Ubuntu`, но все не так просто, нужно выбрать пакет [из этого](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=mono).
Какой из них подойдет для разработки?

Comment: Вопрос плюсую - не плохо если кто-то из "отцов" объяснил как развернуть - скажем на ванильном Дебиане - среду для разработки/выполнения Моно

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю интересует тебя разработка в .NET?
Если так ставь MonoDevelop, можно из репозиториев самой Ubunt'ы или через центр установки программ. Но там довольно старая версия была вроде...
Это IDE для .NET разработки под Linux
Windows Form Application сделать конечно не выйдет.

Answer (score 0):

В репозиториях Ubuntu старые версии  monodevelop. Лучше пользоваться более свежими версиями из сторонних ppa. Например так.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:keks9n/monodevelop-latest 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-latest
```

Само mono runtime, компиляторы и прочие необходимые инструменты будут установлены автоматически.